# Bitcoin core wallet shows a wrong balance

Tags: bitcoin-core, ledger-hardware-wallet, sparrow-wallet

after downloading and running bitcoin core v24.0.1 I connected to Sparrow wallet which in turn was connected to a Ledger hard wallet.
Here is the problem: after bitcoin core did the rescanning the balance shown on Bitcoin core wallet is way different (too low) than the balances shown on Sparrow wallet and the ledger live.
But the funny thing is that if go to “transactions” section on Bitcoin core wallet, all transactions are correct and matching with sparrow and ledger.
I just want to know: Why? And and I could fix this?
Thanks

Comment: I’m having this issue, too. I don’t know whats going on

Comment: Are you looking at the entire wallet, or just an "address balance"? Did you import all the addresses (including change addresses, which are not usually shown)?

Comment: try this and restart wallet
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/120005/bitcoin-core-balance-incorrect-after-connecting-sparrow-wallet/120597#120597?newreg=884cf687d1b648a187a148bb7d0cc28d

Comment: The solution mentioned by Dragos above worked for me.